# How to invoke athena triggered automatically by lambda when objects are updated in the s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

I have following 2 use case to apply on this

Case 1. I would need to call the lambda alone to invoke athena to perform query on s3 data? Question: How to invoke lambda alone via api?

Case 2. I would need lambda function to  invoke athena whenever a file copied to the same s3 bucket that already mapped to the athena?

Iam referring following link to do the same to perform the Lambda operation over athena

Link:
https://dev.classmethod.jp/cloud/run-amazon-athenas-query-with-aws-lambda/

**For the case 2**: Following are eg want to integrate:

File in s3-1 is sales.csv - and i would updating  sales details by copying data from other s3-2 . And the schema/column defined in the s3-1 data would remain same.
so when i copy some file to the same s3 data that mapped to the athena,  the lambda should call athena to perform the query

Appreciate if can provide the better way to achieve above cases?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What do you mean by "any event from the custom list"? How are you invoking the Lambda function? It seems to be retrieving a `name` from the passed-in event and is using that within the Athena query. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein What iam trying to achieve is, how can invoke the query on athena using lambda automatically if we update the data in the same s3 buck which already  mapped to  the athena data base? Correct me please if my use case are not logic-able to apply in this case

Comment: So, it appears your use-case is: When a file is added to the Amazon S3 bucket, use an Amazon S3 event to trigger a Lambda function. The Lambda function will then call Athena to perform a query on the data file that was uploaded. Is that correct? Question: Will the file always be the same file, or might it have a different name? I ask that because Athena needs a `CREATE TABLE` before running a query. Also, will it only be querying the one file, or might it query multiple files within a directory? Feel free to Edit your question to provide more details.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I have edited the question putting 2 cases which i want to achieve. Please let me know if that clear to provide the solution? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Case 1**

An AWS Lambda can be directly invoked via the [`invoke()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html) command. This can be done via the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) or from a programming language using an AWS SDK.

**Case 2**

An **Amazon S3 event** can be configured on a bucket to automatically trigger an AWS Lambda function when a file is uploaded. The event provides the bucket name and file name (object name) to the Lambda function.

The Lambda function can extract these details from the `event` record and can then use that information in an Amazon Athena command.

Please note that, if the file name is different each time, a `CREATE TABLE` command would be required before a `SELECT` command can query the data.

**General Comments**

A Lambda function can run for a maximum of 15 minutes, so make sure the Athena queries do not take more than this time. This is not a particularly efficient use of an AWS Lambda function because it will be billed for the duration of the function call, even if it is just waiting for Athena to finish.

Another option would be to have the Lambda function directly process the file, assuming that the query is not particularly complex. For example, the Lambda function could download the file to temporary storage (maximum 500MB), read through the file, do some calculations (eg add up the total of some columns), then store the results somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The next step wuold be create a end point to your lambda, you ver can use aws-apigateway for that.

On the other hand, using the amazon console or amazon cli, you can invoke the lambda in order to test.